# Do Noetherian rings have the IBN property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

I know that commutative rings and division rings have the invariant basis number property. I'm curious what else are there.

> Do Noetherian rings have the invariant basis number property?

If not, what about Artinian rings or semisimple rings? And how do I prove this?

Comment: The wikipedia page for invariant basis number says Noetherian rings have this property but doesn't list a reference. Since Artinian rings are Noetherian, they also have this property. And semisimple rings are Artinian. More generally, semilocal rings (rings that are semisimple when you quotient by the Jacobson radical) have the ibn property.

Comment: @manthanomen Yeah I know what you wrote after saying Noetherian rings have IBN property.. but I do not believe it so far. I searched for it but could not find an article which proves Noetherian rings have IBN property

Comment: Notice that the zero ring is Noetherian and does not have IBN.

Comment: @HeinrichD Doesn't the definition of a Noetherian ring usually assume the existence of a nonzero $1$?

Comment: @manthanomen: Of course not. The zero ring is noetherian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R\neq\{0\}$ be Noetherian and let $m > n$ be natural numbers. Consider the homomorphism $f ~:~ R^m \to R^n$ given by the projection onto the first $n$ coordinates.

The assumption $R^m\cong R^n$ leads to a contradiction, as $f$ has non-zero kernel but it is also a surjective endomorphism of a Noetherian module, hence bijective (this is easily proved using the ascending chain condition).